# How to get family of azure VM via VM size az cli

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, virtual-machine

I am looking to get the name of the VM family of a specific VM type via the az cli.

Sample input:

```
Standard_D16ds_v4
```

Sample output:

```
Standard DDSv4 Family vCPUs
```

Is this possible to do either via az cli or azure RM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one,

```
az vm show -g 'YourResourceGroupName' -n 'VMName' --query 'hardwareProfile.vmSize' -o tsv
```

Comment: This only works for a VM that already exists. I was looking for something that could tell me what family a size belongs to. I.e, if I enter Standard_D16ds_v4 the script would tell me this belongs to the family of Standard DDSv4 Family vCPUs. And ideal command would be something along the lines of 'az vm getfamily -NodeSize xxxx'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `list-skus` subcommand to find this:

```
$ az vm list-skus --size Standard_D16ds_v4 --query [].family
[
  "standardDDSv4Family"
]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-skus